# Draw and render a sequence of 3D models with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, animation, rendering

I have an application that will generate a 3D model for a dynamic 3D object (3D mesh + texture formatted as .obj file) at a time, so I end up getting a stream of 3D models (or 4D models?), and I want to display and render these time-series 3D models in real-time using OpenGL.

Being a newbie in OpenGL, I’ve tried and managed to display and render one 3D model with OpenGL by loading the .obj to a VBO and drawing it. But I am unsure how to draw and render a stream of 3D models? Specifically, assume that I have all 3D models available beforehand, how can I display and render each 3D model indexed by the time one by one? The next question is if the 3D model is provided on the fly, how can I do that in an online fashion?

Comment: If you have a solution that successfully loads and displays a given model X, can you not simply re-run that solution on the next frame, but with input model X+1 instead, and so on?